# Configure Oracle Sqlldr on Windows 7

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm having a hard time configuring Sqlldr with Windows 7.

- The Oracle client was previously installed by our support team.
- There were no registry settings, but Sqlplus, Toad, and Plsql Developer all worked.
- I copied Sqlldr from another server and put it in the bin directory of my localhost.
- In my environmental variables, I defined Oracle_Home, LD_LIBARY_PATH, and ORACLE_SID.

Now, whether I call the program by the command line or ETL tool, I get:

```
ERROR>Message 2100 not found; 
    No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=ULMessage 2100 not found; 
    No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=UL
```

What gives?

P.s.  It's not a path issue because I can run sqlldr on the command line (with the error)

Comment: So why didn't your support team install SQLLDR?  What version of Oracle client are you using on this server?  Does the source server have the same version of Oracle and the same version of Windows 7?

Comment: Are you using Instant Client rather than the full Oracle Client install?

Comment: Also, as what user are you running SQL*Loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you copy all the sqldr dependent files?  You can't just copy over the binary only.   The oracle sqlldr has dependencies to msg files it needs.  i would suggest getting the client installer for the oracle client that is installed on your win7 box and have it install the sqlldr component that way you have all the dependent files and libraries it needs.  Manually copying the sqlldr from aonther machine is not really supported and not advised.